# FullInformationOutputRegulator -how does it work?

Tags: control-systems

How does this function work? I don't understand how the regulator equation is synthesized when the model is nonlinear. Does it make use of a power series approach? Can someone suggest something to read to have an idea?

Comment: Please, paste a Mathematica code using the expression , its arguments and your function using the FullInformationOutputRegulator expressions. It will help to  see where you coming from.

Comment: Any example from the Wolfram documentation will do. It is a general question. @JoseECalderon

Comment: It uses Taylor series. The theory can be found in the book 'Nonlinear Control Systems' by Alberto Isidori.

Comment: Thank you. So it basically involves a Taylor series expansion restricting the flow on the center manifold? I was just curious because there seams to be no information about this. Also how would one change the order of such an expansion? It is really strange that such an issue isn't explained. @SubaThomas

Comment: Yes. The order can be set using Method -> "FeedbackSolver" -> {"Taylor", "ApproximationOrder" -> ao}, where 'ao' is the approximation order. This design was not finalized, and hence not added to the documentation.

Comment: Brilliant. I was willing to compare this method with Sakamoto's step-integration method. I think you have answered my question. Are there other methods of approximation? @SubaThomas

Comment: There is no implementation for the output regulation in the case of error feedback, am I right? @SubaThomas

Comment: Yes, there is no function for error feedback, and Taylor is the only method that has been implemented for full information.

Comment: @SubaThomas I've noticed that FullInformationOutputRegulator accepts exosystem states having eigenvalues on the origin of the Gauss plane. This certainly is interesting as it implies that internally it must have some sort of error feedback (at least this is how Isidori treats the structurally stable regulation problem).

Comment: Eigenvalues at the origin are on the imaginary axis. I do not see anything special about them? There is no internal dynamics in the regulator returned by `FullInformationOutputRegulator`.

Comment: When one wants to make the dynamical system structurally stable, a augmented exo-system is introduced containing a set of dynamics with eigenvalues on the origin. I've read it again: I was wrong in implying the internal dynamics, nothing much changes except that the regulator is also structurally stable. Perhaps this should be put more clearly in the documentation. @SubaThomas